# javascript style.display not working

Tags: javascript, css

Anyone can tell me why even though by debugging with fireBug the script correctly finds the proper element, the style.display doesn't update the property of the ul which remains set to none?

```
<html>
              <div id="nav">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="" onmouseover="show()">Studio</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
              </div>
              <div id="subnav1">
            <ul style="display: none">
              <li><a href="">normally hidden</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
              </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function show() 
            {
            var subNav1 = document.getElementById("subnav1");
            var ull = subNav1.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            for (var i = 0, ii = ull.length; i < ii; i++) 
            {
                if(ull[i].style.display == "visible") 
                {
                  ull[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                else 
                {
                  ull[i].style.display = "visible";
                }
            }
            };
        </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

"visible" is not a valid css display value. I think you are looking for "block"

Comment: he might also me confusing `display` with `visibility`.  so it is either `style.display = "block"` or `style.visibility = "visible"`

Comment: Ok this is strange, you are right that visible doesn't exist, however what baffles me is that if I put style="display: visible" with firebug the ul appears, if I put style="display: none"  it disappears.. I therefore inferred visible keyword was ok